# Splitting a Loop into Subloops

Tags: r, json, loops, web-scraping

I have this loop in R that is scraping Reddit comments from an API incrementally on a minute basis (e.g. all comments containing a certain keyword between now and 1 minute ago, 1 minute ago and 2 minutes ago, 2 minutes ago and 3 minutes ago, etc.):

```
library(jsonlite)

part1 = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=trump&after="    
part2 = "m&before="
part3 = "m&size=500"

results = list()
for (i in 1:526000)
{tryCatch({
    {
        url_i<-  paste0(part1, i+1,  part2, i,  part3)
        r_i <-  data.frame(fromJSON(url_i))
        results[[i]] <- r_i

myvec_i <- sapply(results, NROW)

print(c(i, sum(myvec_i))) 
       
       
    }
}, error = function(e){})
}
final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
saveRDS(final, "final.RDS")
```

I would like to split this loop up so that it runs in segments of 20000 iterations, saves each segment, and then continues to the next segment.

This is the code I am using:

```
index = seq(1, 526000, by = 20000)

max = as.numeric(length(index) -1 )

###########################################

results = list()

for (i in 1:max)
    
{tryCatch({
    
    {
        start_i = index[i]
        
        end_i = index[i+1]
        
        
        url_i<-  paste0(part1, end_i,  part2, start_i,  part3)
        
        resource_i <-  data.frame(fromJSON(url_i))
        
        results[[i]] <- r_i
        
        myvec_i <- sapply(results, NROW)
        print(c(i, sum(myvec_i)))
        
    }
    
}, error = function(e){})
    
    final_i = do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
    title_i = paste0("file_", i, ".RDS")
    saveRDS(final_i, title_i )
    
}
```

I am not sure if I have done this correctly - can someone please show me how to do this correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: You may use `start <- index[-length(index)];end <- index[-1] - 1; for(i in seq_along(start)) {start_i <- start[i]; end_i <- end[i];...}`

Comment: thanks @akrun! I am currently running an R script my computer that is connecting to the API so I can't run a new script without interrupting the previous script - I posted your answer as a new answer below? Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: If you want to post this answer yourself - I will delete mine and you can post yours. I will also accept your answer as the official answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually that is not correct.  Assuming that you want to get the sequence from 1 to 526000 instead of every 20000

Comment: Please do check whether the code works or not.  I haven't tested it as your loop is so big

Comment: Thanks again! I will run your code tomorrow (or whenever the existing script finishes running). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logic is to loop over each block, get the sequence ('index'), create the 'start' as index and 'end' is 1 subtracted from 1 after removing the first element and appending the 526000 (as index last element is 520001.  Loop over the sequence of 'start', extract the corresponding 'start', 'end' from that index (`start_i`, `end_i`), then loop over the sequence between the `start_i:end_i` and apply the code while appending the output to `result` `list`

```
 index <- seq(1, 526000, by = 20000)
  start <- index
  end <- c(index[-1] - 1, 526000)
  
   
  part1 <- "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=trump&after="    
  part2 <- "m&before="
  part3 <- "m&size=500"
  results <- list()
   
for(i in seq_along(start)) {
    
   
    
           start_i <- start[i]
           end_i <- end[i]
           for(j in start_i:end_i) {  
             tryCatch({         
        
        
                   url_j<-  paste0(part1, j+1,  part2, j,  part3)
        
                    resource_j <-  data.frame(fromJSON(url_j))
        
                    results[[j]] <- resource_j
        
                    myvec_j <- sapply(results, NROW)
                    print(c(j, sum(myvec_j)))
                
                
    
                }, error = function(e){
              })
    
                final_j = do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
                title_j = paste0("file_", j, ".RDS")
                saveRDS(final_j, title_j )
    
                }
                
    }
```

Comment: @ akrun: I have been working on a question involving loops - if you have time, can you please take a look at it? Thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76195071/r-randomly-sampling-groups-of-coin-flips

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment provided by @akrun:

```
library(jsonlite)

part1 = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=trump&after="

part2 = "m&before="

part3 = "m&size=500"

index = seq(1, 526000, by = 20000)

max = as.numeric(length(index) -1 )

start <- index[-length(index)]

end <- index[-1] - 1

###########################################

results = list()

for(i in seq_along(start)) {
    
    {tryCatch({
        
        {
            
            start_i <- start[i]
            end_i <- end[i]
            
            
            url_i<-  paste0(part1, end_i,  part2, start_i,  part3)
            
            resource_i <-  data.frame(fromJSON(url_i))
            
            results[[i]] <- r_i
            
            myvec_i <- sapply(results, NROW)
            print(c(i, sum(myvec_i)))
            
        }
        
    }, error = function(e){})
        
        final_i = do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
        title_i = paste0("file_", i, ".RDS")
        saveRDS(final_i, title_i )
        
    }
```

@akrun: Is this what you meant? Thank you!