# R: Randomly Sampling Groups of Coin Flips

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose:

- There is a coin where if it lands head then the probability of the next flip being heads is 0.6 (and if tails then the next flip being tails is also 0.6)
- There are 100 students in a class
- Each student flips this coin a random number of times
- The last flip of student_n does not influence the first flip of student_n+1 (i.e. when the next student flips the coin, the first flip has 0.5 probability of heads or tails, but the next flip for this student depends on the previous flip)

Here is some R code to represent this problem:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76192042/r-verifying-the-results-of-coin-flips
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
ids <- 1:100
student_id <- sort(sample(ids, 100000, replace = TRUE))
coin_result <- character(1000)
coin_result[1] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)

for (i in 2:length(coin_result)) {
  if (student_id[i] != student_id[i-1]) {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)
  } else if (coin_result[i-1] == "H") {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
  } else {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))
  }
}

#tidy up
my_data <- data.frame(student_id, coin_result)
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$student_id),]

final <- my_data %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    mutate(flip_number = row_number())
```

From this data, we can count the number of times sequences of HH, HT, TH and TT occurred:

```
head(my_data)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   student_id [1]
  student_id coin_result  flip_number
       <int> <chr>              <int>
1          1 H                      1
2          1 H                      2
3          1 H                      3
4          1 H                      4
5          1 T                      5
6          1 H                      6

my_data %>%
  group_by(student_id) %>%
  summarize(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
  count(Sequence)

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Sequence     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 HH       29763
2 HT       19782
3 TH       19775
4 TT       30580
```

**My Problem:** Using this data, I am trying to accomplish the following task:

- Step 1: Using sampling with replacement, select 100 students
- Step 2: For a given student that is selected in Step 1, randomly choose a position in their sequence of flips (e.g. call this position "x")
- Step 3: For this same student, randomly choose a second position in their sequence of flips (e.g. call this position "y") such that y > x (i.e. "y" comes after "x").
- Step 4: Repeat Step 2 and Step 3 for all students selected in Step 1
- Step 5: Count the number of times sequences of HH, HT, TH and TT occurred for all students selected in Step 1
- Step 6: Repeat Step 1 - Step 5 many times (e.g. 1000 times)

As an example, suppose Student 15 has 6 Flips : `H, H, T, H, T, T`  - if x = 2 and y = 5, then we would have `H, T, H, T`

**Here is my own attempt at solving my problem:**

```
# Set the number of iterations
k <- 1000

# Initialize a data frame 
results <- data.frame(iteration_number = numeric(0),
                      h_given_h = numeric(0),
                      h_given_t = numeric(0),
                      t_given_h = numeric(0),
                      t_given_t = numeric(0))

# Set the number of students to sample
n_students <- length(unique(my_data$student_id))

# Loop over the number of iterations
for (i in 1:k) {
  # Randomly sample student ids with replacement
  sampled_ids <- sample(ids, n_students, replace = TRUE)
  
  # Initialize a data frame to store the sampled data
  sampled_data <- data.frame(student_id = integer(0), coin_result = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  # LOOP
  for (j in sampled_ids) {
    # Get data for the current student
    student_data <- my_data[my_data$student_id == j, ]
    
    # Randomly choose a starting and ending point
    x <- sample(nrow(student_data), 1)
    y <- sample(x:nrow(student_data), 1)
    
    # Select the data between the starting and ending point
    selected_data <- student_data[x:y, ]
    
    # Append the selected data to the sampled data frame
    sampled_data <- rbind(sampled_data, selected_data)
  }
  
  final <- sampled_data %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    mutate(flip_number = row_number())
  
  # Calculate the conditional probabilities
  cond_prob <- final %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    summarize(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
    count(Sequence) %>%
    mutate(prob = n / sum(n))
  
  # Extract probabilities
  p_HH <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "HH"]
  p_HT <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "HT"]
  p_TH <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "TH"]
  p_TT <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "TT"]

  #print(i)
  # Append 
  results[i, ] <- c(i, p_HH, p_HT, p_TH, p_TT)
}

colnames(results) <- c("iteration_number", "h_given_h", "h_given_t", "t_given_h", "t_given_t")

library(ggplot2)

# Convert to long 
results_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(results, cols = c(h_given_h, h_given_t, t_given_h, t_given_t), names_to = "condition", values_to = "probability")

# Plot
ggplot(results_long, aes(x = iteration_number, y = probability, color = condition)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Iteration", y = "Probability", color = "Condition")
```

[image]

**My Question:** While the code seems to have run, I am not sure if I have done this correctly. Can someone please help me confirm this?

**For example -  shouldn't the lines for HH and TT be almost identical .... and shouldn't the lines of TH and HT be almost identical? Yet in my graph, this clearly not the case? The way I see it, within a given iteration, if the same student appears 3 times in the re-sampled dataset, the last transition from the first time will "leak" into the the first transition from the second time and thus compromise the results.**

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because :  please do NOT double-post questions.  Edit your original post

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft: Thank you for your reply! I have not doubled posted a question. This new question is a follow up a previous question - I simply posted a reference to the previous question for context. In the previous question, I asked about how to simulate correlated coin flip data. In this new question, I am asking how to write a loop to randomly resample the data based on a certain condition. Thus, I do not believe I have double posted any question. Thank you so much!

Comment: The only thing is that the question is quite long. Do you think you could shorten it by pointing out the main point. I know sometimes it is not possible!:-)

Comment: I think I see a problem in my own code ... within a given iteration, if the same student appears 3 times in the re-sampled dataset, the last transition from the first time will "leak" into the the first transition from the second time and thus compromise the results. Is my logic correct?

Comment: @ tarjae: thank you for your reply! I will try to shorten it!

Comment: The issue comes from how you've sampled the data.  You generate only 1000 initial flips and then these are recycled 100 times across your 100 (uneven) student ids. So you're resampling from the same data over and over in your simulation and any 'noise' present in the original 1000 flips is echoed in each simulation iteration.  If each student had a random sample of flips (instead of the same recycled set) the issue would disappear.

Comment: Instead of generating the data once and repeating the sampling process you could generate the data and do the sampling process in the same interaction

Comment: @ M Aurélio: Thank yous o much for your reply! I will also look into this!

Comment: @ Ritchie Sacramento: Thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, can you please show me what you mean by this? I am trying to modify my code based on your suggestions. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that we can find the result you want by doing repetitions of the simulation process together with the sampling process. I will demonstrate this by creating functions to simulate the data and sample it according to the code you wrote

##### Function to simulate data

```r
sim_data <- function(n_students){
ids <- 1:n_students
student_id <- sort(sample(ids, 100000, replace = TRUE))
coin_result <- character(1000)
coin_result[1] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)

for (i in 2:length(coin_result)) {
  if (student_id[i] != student_id[i-1]) {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)
  } else if (coin_result[i-1] == "H") {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
  } else {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))
  }
}

data.frame(student_id, coin_result) %>% 
  arrange(student_id) %>% 
  group_by(student_id) %>%
  mutate(flip_number = row_number())
}

dt <- sim_data(100)
```

##### Function for sampling

```r
Sampling <- function(my_data, n_sample = 100){

  # Step 1
  n_students <- length(unique(my_data$student_id))
  sampled_ids <- sample(1:n_students, n_sample, replace = TRUE)
  sampled_data <- data.frame(student_id = integer(0), 
coin_result = character(0), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  for (j in seq_along(sampled_ids)) {
  # Step 2
    student_data <- my_data[my_data$student_id == sampled_ids[j], ]
    
    x <- sample(nrow(student_data), 1)
    
  # Step 3  
    # There is a edge case where position x is the last flip in the sequence, for 
    # all other cases we shouldn't use position "x" in the sample
    if (x == nrow(student_data)) y <- x else
    y <- sample((x + 1):nrow(student_data), 1)
    selected_data <- student_data[x:y,] %>% 
    mutate(loop_id = j)
    
    sampled_data <- rbind(sampled_data, selected_data)
  }
  
  # Step 5  
  cond_prob <- 
    sampled_data %>%
    group_by(loop_id) %>%
    mutate(flip_number = row_number()) %>% 
    mutate(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result))) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    count(Sequence) %>%
    mutate(prob = n / sum(n))
  
  
  p_HH <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "HH"]
  p_HT <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "HT"]
  p_TH <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "TH"]
  p_TT <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "TT"]
  
  c("h_given_h" = p_HH,"h_given_t" =  p_HT, "t_given_h" = p_TH, "t_given_t" = p_TT)
}
```

Comparing the methods across `k = 100` replications we get the following results:

```r
n_replicate <- 100

results_1 <- 
  replicate(n_replicate,Sampling(dt)) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rowid_to_column('iteration_number') 

results_2 <- replicate(n_replicate,{
  sim_data(100) %>% 
  Sampling()
  } ) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rowid_to_column('iteration_number') 

 bind_rows("OP" = results_1,"Sample different data" = results_2, .id = "sample_method") %>% 
   tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(h_given_h, h_given_t, t_given_h, t_given_t), names_to = "condition", values_to = "probability") %>%
   summarise(prob = mean(probability), .by = c(sample_method, condition)) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = sample_method, values_from = prob ) 
#> A tibble: 4 × 3
#>  condition    OP `Sample different data`
#>  <chr>     <dbl>                   <dbl>
#> 1 h_given_h 0.283                   0.305
#> 2 h_given_t 0.203                   0.199
#> 3 t_given_h 0.203                   0.199
#> 4 t_given_t 0.311                   0.297

library(ggplot2)

  bind_rows(results_1, results_2, .id = "sample_method") %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(h_given_h, h_given_t, t_given_h, t_given_t), names_to = "condition", values_to = "probability") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = iteration_number, y = probability, color = condition)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Iteration", y = "Probability", color = "Condition") +
    facet_wrap(~sample_method, labeller = labeller(sample_method = c("1" = "OP", "2" = "Sample different data") ) )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

##### Edit

The way the conditional probability is calculated is also not ideal. The best way to estimate the probability of "H" given "H", would be to do the number of coins that had the result "H" and on the next coin the result "H" again. The way you are presenting it is closer to estimating the marginal probability of the combinations P(HH) and P(HT) than P(H|H) and P(T|H).

Comment: @ M Aurélio: thank you so much for your answer! In the graph you made, is there any reason that the purple/red lines appear more different compared to the bottom two lines? Thank you so much!

Comment: My guess would be the standard error introduced by sampling.  I believe that increasing the sample size should smooth out these curves by decreasing the distance from the true expected value.